# Are legal question regarding martial arts on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Just to clarify something... Do we want to accept legal question with regards to martial arts?

So, would a question on the legality of training in art X or carrying weapons or what court X said about marital art Y or something like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it should be off topic.**

Mainly because we are martial art experts and not lawyers.  A second compelling reason is that the law changes depending on local and thus any answer would be too localized to be of any use.

Comment: I would agree - anything that can be answered with certainty (i.e. quoting law or precedents) would likely be to localised and/or subject to change due to specifics of each case. Having said that we can still tangentially refer to legal matters, we just shouldn't discuss them specifically.