# Isn't legality off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Why is this question about legality still open? [Krav Maga, is it 100% legal for defense?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/1919/5961)

The [on-topic help](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says

> Questions that should not be asked on Martial Arts include:
>
> ...
>
> - Legalities of martial arts (off-topic)

My reading is this is definitely off-topic now. Unless someone voices a defense of keeping it open, I will close.

It looks like legality was declared off-topic in 2014, after the question was asked, and there was a vote to close in 2017 that did not result in closure.

Comment: [relevant meta question](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/are-legal-question-regarding-martial-arts-on-topic). I would agree it was a missed retro closure.

Comment: I would lock it with the historical option, as it was on topic when it was originally asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! (and of course I have a vested interest in this particular one :)

I'd be in favor of John's historical lock suggestion. I think it's important to keep this question because:

- the currently marked answer does manage to avoid talking about legal specifics
- it is inherently answerable
- **due to mystique and misinformation many other random visitors are likely to have the same (or similar) questions** (so it is a useful reference question)

With regards to the *Legalities of martial arts* off topic option I think it is useful to break it down a bit:

- we (I) are not lawyers so are not necessarily qualified to talk about legal specifics
- laws are different everywhere, this can lead to very localized answers
- laws are interpreted, which can lead to arguments
- like medicine, law is a privileged and specialist topic

so while we should try and avoid questions about legal **specifics**, I feel there is no reason why we can't still ask questions about legalities **in general**, which is what this question does.

Of course the simple answer for the linked question would have been *"Well, duh, yes..."*, but I think it's important that we have the flexibility to expound on these where necessary, even if we come at it from a philosophical view point.